# setting up duplicate http and https locations in apache 2.2

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, https

I have
VirtualHost *:80 tag with many Locations with authentication defined in it.
Now I just added https. do I need to replicate all of these Locations under

VirualHost *:443?
is there any easy way for both host to share locations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your Location configurations to their own file, and [include](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#include) that file inside both VirtualHost configurations.